# Bootstrap 4 tab.js active states stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

2 of the 4 `tab.js` examples aren't working for me in CodePen and a local html file. In the "nav" example the items in the dropdown stay active and can't be accessed again after clicking way. Same goes for all the items in the vertical tabs: https://codepen.io/DannyJoris/pen/MvqMEW

At first I thought maybe there's a bug in the provided code snippets, but the bugs persist even when I copy the markup of the working example using the inspector tool. That makes me think something is wrong in the way I include the Bootstrap files.

These are the included CDN files:

CSS:

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css

JavaScript:

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.0.8/popper.min.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js

Tested on macOS 10.12.6, Chrome 60 & Firefox 55

Edit: it does work when using Bootstrap 3.3.7: https://codepen.io/DannyJoris/pen/VzEZmw, so it must be a bug in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is resolved in beta: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23708#issuecomment-325263323

Answer (score 2):

If your issue is related to the vertical and pills I may suggest to add the following handlers:

```
$('.nav-pills > a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
})
$('.nav-pills .dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    $(this).siblings().find('.active').removeClass('active');
})
```

Remember: the IDs must be unique (refer: myTab)

```js
$('.nav-pills > a').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
})
$('.nav-pills .dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    $(this).siblings().find('.active').removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
#v-pills-tab {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}

#v-pills-tabContent {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h2 {
    margin: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <!-- ul -->
    <h2>ul</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="true">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown1-tab" href="#dropdown1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="dropdown1">@fat</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown2-tab" href="#dropdown2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="dropdown2">@mdo</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">1...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">2...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dropdown1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="dropdown1-tab">3...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dropdown2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="dropdown2-tab">4...</div>
    </div>

    <!-- nav -->
    <h2>nav</h2>
    <nav class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab1" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-expanded="true">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile">Profile</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" id="nav-dropdown1-tab" href="#nav-dropdown1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="nav-dropdown1">@fat</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" id="nav-dropdown2-tab" href="#nav-dropdown2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="nav-dropdown2">@mdo</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">1...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">2...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-dropdown1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-dropdown1-tab">3...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-dropdown2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-dropdown2-tab">4...</div>
    </div>

    <!-- pills -->
    <h2>pills</h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-expanded="true">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-expanded="true">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" id="pills-dropdown1-tab" href="#pills-dropdown1" role="tab" data-toggle="pill" aria-controls="pills-dropdown1">@fat</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" id="pills-dropdown2-tab" href="#pills-dropdown2" role="tab" data-toggle="pill" aria-controls="pills-dropdown2">@mdo</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">1...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">2...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-dropdown1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-dropdown1-tab">3...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-dropdown2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-dropdown2-tab">4...</div>
    </div>

    <!-- vertical -->
    <h2>vertical</h2>
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-expanded="true">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-expanded="true">Profile</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-expanded="true">Messages</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-expanded="true">Settings</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">1...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">2...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">3...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">4...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! While this snippet works, shouldn't this be part of bootstrap? Also, updated the duplicate IDs.

Comment: I don't have an answer for this. I may only suggest to use js whenever you need. I assume in the final release of bostrap all the issues will be solved.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. I submitted an issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23708

Comment: 2020 here with v4.4.1 and this is still an issue when trying to have two separate menus manipulating the same tab panes. Fortunately, @gaetanoM 's solution works! Worked for me. Thank you sir!